# How to use similarity matrix in hclust

Tags: r, hclust

I have a matrix which represents similarity between nodes, how can I use it in `hclust` method which takes dissimilarity matrices ?

does setting dissimilarity to +1 and similarity to negative values solves the problem ? for example...

```
 bank.albert    bank.gloucester bank.laurier    bank.lisgar
bank-albert 0   1   1   1
bank-gloucester 1   0   -5036.625   1
bank-laurier    1   -5036.625   0   1
bank-lisgar 1   1   1   0
bank-nepean 1   -6524.875   1   -7438.375
```

Comment: I your similarity is scaled to [0,1] (and symmetric), you could use `dissimilarity = 1 - similarity`.

Comment: @EDi please check the edit